# null reference exception while generating pdf using itext7

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am trying to insert values in a PDF placeholder using itext 7 and i am using itext7 7.2.5.

I am getting null exception error in the line mentioned below, how ever the null exception is not causing any issue in local machine and filling the PDF form as expected but, when in development server it is breaking the workflow. has anyone faced the similar issue and how to fix it.

```
public void file1(int id)
{
    try
    {
        String empid;




        var selectResult = (from s in _context.EmployeeBasicInformations
                            where s.EmployeeId == id
                            select new { Name = "Mr. " + s.EmployeeFirstName, ids = s.EmployeeId }).ToList();

        var getinfo = (from i in _context.EmployeeBasicInformations where i.EmployeeId == id select i).Single();

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/OriginalPDF/1-EMPLOYEE JOINING FORM_revised.pdf");

        string path = "C:/New folder/" + getinfo.EmployeeEmail + "/IndPDF/";

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }


        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(path + "cover.pdf");




        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        iText.Layout.Element.Image fox = new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(FOX));
        fox.SetFixedPosition(285, 640);
        document.Add(fox);

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true); // <-- Null Exception Here

        // iterate selectResult
        foreach (var item in selectResult)
        {

            empid = item.ids.ToString();
            form.GetField("text_1glqt").SetValue(item.Name).SetFontSize(10);
            form.GetField("text_2rjsn").SetValue(empid).SetFontSize(13);

        }
        form.FlattenFields();
        pdfDocument.Close();
        document.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("File1 Method" + ex);
    }
}
```

The below is the stack error.

```
>   handbook.dll!handbook.Controllers.PDFController.PDFController.file1(int id) Line 118    C#
    handbook.dll!handbook.Controllers.PDFController.PDFController.Index(int id) Line 57 C#
    [Lightweight Function]  
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync.__Logged|12_1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker invoker)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAwaitedAsync()  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.OnActionExecutionAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutionDelegate next)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ControllerActionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutionDelegate next)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync.__Logged|17_1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker invoker)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerRequestDelegateFactory.CreateRequestDelegate.AnonymousMethod__0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilterAsync(Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, string requestId, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)   Unknown
    Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.VsContentMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context context)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IHttpApplication<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context> application)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IHttpApplication<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context> application)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Stream<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>.Execute() Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()  Unknown
```

Comment: Please share the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: HI @mkl i have added the comments in the question . please check and help.

Comment: The trace you posted contains the information up to `PDFController.file1`. Can you also determine the trace from there into the iText code to the point at which the exception occurs?